# C# How do I stop code from looping during collection serialization causing a stackoverflow?

Tags: c#, serialization, collections, .net-4.5

I have a `ContactForm` object that contains several nested collection objects.  When I attempt to serialize the object, the code gets stuck in a loop within the `SectionCollectionObject`.

Here is the code that executes the `serialize()` call:

```
public static ContactForm SaveForm(ContactForm cf)
{
    if (cf != null)
    {  
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(cf.GetType());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            xs.Serialize(sw, cf);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

the program gets stuck in a loop at the "get" statement until it throws a `StackOverflowException`. What needs to be changed or added to the code to get past this point?

Here is the `SectionObjectCollection` class:

```
[Serializable, XmlInclude(typeof(Section))]
public sealed class SectionObjectCollection : Collection<Section>
{
    public Section this[int index]
    {            
        get {
            return (Section)this[index]; //loops here with index always [0]
        }
        set {
            this[index] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `Section` class that the collection class inherits from:

```
public class Section
{
    public Section() 
    {
        Questions = new QuestionObjectCollection();
    }

    public int SectionDefinitionIdentity {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public bool ShowInReview {get;set;} 
    public int SortOrder {get;set;}

    public QuestionObjectCollection Questions
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace for the exception you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indexer will always loop indefinitely, regardless of whether you're using it in a serialization context or not. You probably want to call the base indexer inside it like this:

```
public Section this[int index]
{            
    get {
        return (Section)base[index]; //loops here with index always [0]
    }
    set {
        base[index] = value;
    }
}
```